# Смысл фразы "замечания приняты к исправлению"

Tags: литература, семантика, лексика

Какой смысл выражения "замечания приняты к исправлению"?

1. Замечания исправляются.
2. Замечания доведены до сведения.
3. -

Answer (score 3):

У слова принять есть значение № 5 (по Ожегову)-Услышав, узнав, воспринять. Молча п.тяжелое известие. П. к сведению что-н.

В клише "принять к сведению/к исполнению/к исправлению" смысл таков: Услышав, воспринять, т.е.принять и усвоить,приложив (отнеся его)к чему-либо т.е. распознать как сообщение для сведения, для исполнения, для исправления.
Резолюция - руководство к действию, информация - побуждение к чему-либо.

Замечания приняты к исправлению - отчёт о том, что замечания услышаны и восприняты как побуждение к исправлению, т.е.ошибки, указанные в них, будут исправлены

Comment: "к исправлению" в сочетании с "замечаниями" здесь никак не проходит.

Comment: Говоря о канцелярских клише, мы не ищем "нормальной " сочетаемости. Словосочетание в клише заменяет целое предложение.Замечания могут быть разные, но в административной работе они носят предписывающий характер(замечания при проверке, ревизии = указанию).Есть клише "применить к...".Вот здесь некая контаминация: я Вас услышал и замечания (предписания)применю к деятельности по исполнению, т.е. исправлению. Коротко: принял к исправлению.Но документация всегда обезличена, значит, замечания приняты к исполнению = услышал и сделаю.

Comment: В конце классного журнала проверяющие пишут свои замечания. Заканчивается запись словами "Замечания устранить до (дата)". Учитель, прочитав, исправив недочеты. должен написать: замечания устранены такого-то... Это только в нашей школе такая бюрократия? 
Здесь какая-то привычная метонимия: слово замечание называет само замечание и ошибку, недочет, по поводу которого оно сделано.

Comment: Да уж!... Первый раз такое слышу.Метонимия налицо. У нас пишут "недочёты устранить".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что смысл здесь такой: "С замечаниями согласны и собираемся исправить недостатки, отмеченные в этих замечаниях".
Для того чтобы обещания не остались лишь обещаниями, существует понятие контроля за исполнением данных обещаний.

Comment: Спасибо. Это верно со стороны принимающего замечания. А если со стороны дающего замечания? "С замечаниями согласны и собираются исправить недостатки"? Обещания чужие так и могут остаться обещаниями.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза некорректна, как минимум - лексически. Спрашивать, что она значит, надо у того бюрократа, который её соорудил.

С позиции же логики и русского языка *к исправлению* можно принять бракованный товар или, например, рукопись. 
Замечания - к сведению, рекламацию - к устранению (хотя это уже не совсем точно). 
Но исправлять можно и нужно недостатки, никак не замечания.